# How to handle Django Singals emitted by multiple models using a common function

Tags: django, django-signals

I would like to write a common function to handle the post_save signal emitted by Django for multiple models.

**models.py**

```
Class FirstModel(models.Model):
    pass

Class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    pass

Class YetAnotherModel(models.Model):
    pass
```

For some models (**FirstModel**, **AnotherModel**) in my models.py I need to write a function which can do some common action post save.

AFAIK, I can write two handler functions to receive the emitted signals and do the common action.

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=FirstModel)
def first_model_post_save_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    pass

@receiver(post_save, sender=AnotherModel)
def another_model_post_save_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    pass
```

However I am interested in knowing any better solution to make it like a configuration.

**configuration.py**

```
MODELS_TO_BE_POST_SAVE_HANDLED = ['FirstModel', 'AnotherModel']
```

**singals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MODELS_TO_BE_POST_SAVE_HANDLED)
def first_model_post_save_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `post_save.connect()` instead of `@receiver(post_save...)`.

Either as

```python
post_save.connect(model_post_save_handler, sender=FirstModel)
post_save.connect(model_post_save_handler, sender=SecondModel)
```

or as

```python
for model in MODELS_TO_BE_POST_SAVE_HANDLED:
    post_save.connect(model_post_save_handler, sender=model)
```

Also take a look at the [signals documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/), it's worth reading.